# Game server for turn based card game needed!

Tags: android, ios, game-development, server

We are looking for a server for a game we want to build. The game is built for iOS and Android devices, and the clients need to be able to play against each other.
The game architecture would be to connect several users together, including the server as the admin of the game.

The idea is that a chat-room like object will be created for each game session, and the server would add several users into it, including itself.

Then, the server would synchronise all users for a "ready" state and start the game.

The game will be based on XML or JSON objects sent between all entities.

The server needs to be able to join and get notified about users that login, and leave the game, and act accordingly.

We saw the XMPP server solutions as we thought it would be a good candidate, but it seems like the functions of the server that we need cannot be programmed, rather it seems pretty straightforward.

The game should be based over TCP/IP protocol, therefore Websockets for the clients seem like a viable solution.

It is the servers management that we need to figure out how to accomplish.

What are the viable, available solutions for our needs out there?